# Execute Sub after a certian amount of time?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to execute a Sub after a certain time period after a UserForm has open. The UserForm opens immediately when Access has started. Is there an alternative to `Application.OnTime`? As it does not work with Access and only seems to work with Excel.

This is what I'm working with.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Set objWSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
DesktopDir = objWSHShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"
InstallDir = Left(DesktopDir, 3) & "VICI"
VICIMxDir = InstallDir & "\VICI Mx.txt"
VICIFmDir = InstallDir & "\VICI Fm.txt"
VICIAnalyticsDir = InstallDir & "\VICI Analytics.txt"
With ListBox_Status
    If FSO.FileExists(VICIMxDir) = True Then 'Both exist
        .Column(1, 0) = "Ready"
    Else
        .Column(1, 0) = "Not Found"
    End If
    If FSO.FileExists(VICIFmDir) = True Then
        .Column(1, 1) = "Ready"
    Else
        .Column(1, 1) = "Not Found"
    End If
    If FSO.FileExists(VICIAnalyticsDir) = True Then
        .Column(1, 2) = "Ready"
    Else
        .Column(1, 2) = "Not Found"
    End If
.Column(1, 3) = Environ("UserName")
End With
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "DB_BackUP"
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:20"), "RmvDBBackup"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you looked at a Windows timer? http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx

Comment: You can put the `TimerInterval` in the Open event of your Form. `Me.TimerInterval = 500000` And then in the Timer event of your Form you place this code `DoCmd.RunMacro "DB_BackUP"` Hope I have understood your query?

Comment: @SiddharthRout This I will work for what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: I am confused. You are referring to Access Form or VBA Userform?

Comment: I'm sorry. It is a VBA Userform that is opened via Access.

Comment: Why would you use a VBA Userform in Access?

Comment: @Andre Mostly because the VBA UserForm is more easily accessible from other office products and I can call on it no matter the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Application.Wait`:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
waitTime (3000) ' 3 seconds
MyDeleyedMethod
End Sub

Function waitTime(ByVal millsec As Double)
Application.Wait (Now() + millsec / 24 / 60 / 60 / 1000)
End Function

Private Sub MydelayedMethod()
MsgBox ("hello")
End Sub
```

Another way to achieve that result is:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Wait (3) ' 3 seconds
MyDeleyedMethod
End Sub

Sub Wait(seconds As Integer)
Dim now As Long
now = Timer()
Do
    DoEvents
Loop While (Timer < now + seconds)
End Sub

Private Sub MyDeleyedMethod()
MsgBox ("hello")
End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.Wait` is Specific to Excel only. This would work fine but I am using a VBA UserForm with in Access.

Comment: @Quint I have updated my answer, I am not that familiar with access but in the second alternative you do not need to use `Application.Wait`.

Comment: Your solution worked but it seems to be a problem with `UserForm_Activation`. It seems to not execute the code until after the userform has loaded but does it while the userform is loading. The problem I was having was that the UserForm would load in gray and stay gray until the files were moved to a back up location. Your solution worked but also increased the amount of time the UserForm loaded in gray.

Comment: in that case use `UserForm_Initialize()` event

Comment: The `UserForm_Initialize()` event is called before `UserForm_Activation`. So it would end up doing the same thing. We ended up finding the problem tho. The files that it moves are on a networked drive that is very busy so that explains on why the userform would load instantly and at time would stay grey until the file were moved to a backup location based on how much traffic there is to the drive.